# Bundle.main.path(forResource:) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For reasons unknown to me I cannot locate file:

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "REGION_DETAILS_41", ofType: ".zip")
```

It's strange, because when I list all files present in resources directory, it is there. I can find other files, but not this one.
I've also tried different configurations of searching, like:

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "REGION_DETAILS_41.zip", ofType: nil)
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "REGION_DETAILS_41.zip", ofType: "")
```

but with no success.

EDIT:
The following fails as well:

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "REGION_DETAILS_41", ofType: "zip")
```

EDIT2:
I verify if it's present there by checking what is my resources folder and checking its contents:

```
Bundle.main.resourcePath
FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: myResourcesFolder)
```

[image]

Also I've checked in finder it's actually there.

It is included in copy Bundle Resources:

[image]

Comment: *How* did you verify that the file *is* present in the resources?

Comment: Check if you have this file into your `Copy bundle resource`

Comment: The file system on iOS devices is case-sensitive: "zip" != "ZIP"

Comment: @MartinR owe you a nice beer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r:
The file system on iOS devices is case-sensitive: "zip" != "ZIP".
After changing to ZIP it worked perfectly.

Comment: It might be a good idea to rename the file to "zip", to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

First thing is check if you have copied this ZIP file into a bundle at the time adding by looking into `Copy Bundle Resource`.

Following code is tested and you can able to access zip file through it :

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "REGION_DETAILS_41", ofType: "zip")
```

Comment: I've checked it and it's present there.

Comment: @izik461 I tried this code it's working on my side. There must be something wrong at the time of adding. Please check targets you have added in project

Comment: otherwise just remove the file from the project and add it again and then check.